# How to Pass Two-dimensional array from C to Python

Tags: python, c++, c

I want to pass the two-dimensional array to python from C.

How can I use the `Py_BuildValue()` and `PyEval_CallObject()`?

For example, i can use the following code to pass string from C to python:

```
pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("python_code");
pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "main");
pParam = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "HEHEHE");
pResult = PyEval_CallObject(pFunc,pParam);
```

Now, i want to pass the two-dimensional array and a string to python

Comment: Do you with to `return` a list or to alter a list argument?  If you don't know then returning is easier.

Comment: You might also wish to consider ctypes in the standard library.

Comment: can you show us your code and sample data you want to pass to python?

Comment: I just want to pass the "vector<vector<int> > arr" to python function, in python, it can be tuple or list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically, you want to **build** a tuple, not **parse** one.

This is just a straightforward example of how you could convert your `arr` to a tuple of tuples. Here you should add some error checking at some point in time as well.

```
Py_ssize_t len = arr.size();
PyObject *result = PyTuple_New(len);
for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Py_ssize_t len = arr[i].size();
    PyObject *item = PyTuple_New(len);
    for (Py_ssize_t j = 0; j < len; j++)
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(item, j, PyInt_FromLong(arr[i][j]));
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(result, i, item);
}
```

(For Python 3 C API, replace `PyInt_FromLong(arr[i][j])` with  `PyLong_FromLong(arr[i][j])`)

Then you can build your args, like you did with the string. Instead of `s` for string, you would use `O` for `PyObject *` (or `N` if you don't want to increment the reference count):

```
pParam = Py_BuildValue("(O)", result);
```

Maybe [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) could provide a simpler method, but I don't realy know the library myself.

Comment: Thankyou tynn, then how to send the value to python scripty after building the tuple. For example, i used this code to send the string: pParam = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "HEHEHE"); pResult = PyEval_CallObject(pFunc,pParam);

Answer (score 0):

second loop needs a subtile change from:

`for (Py_ssize_t j = 0; i < len; j++)`

to

`for (Py_ssize_t j = 0; j < len; j++)`

with the right running condition statement.